# Kalman Filter. GPS + accelerometer

Tags: java, android, gps, kalman-filter

I know that there are a lot of articles on the internets. But I can't wrap my head around it. 
And I'm asking for your help.

I'm using `apache.math Kalman` filter. I've read their example. But seems like they only observe a position. In my case I want to be velocity oriented.

I know that creating separate Kalman filters is a bad idea. But since GPS has different accuracy on each step and my sample rate varies the matrices(A, B, etc.) should be recalculated between each Kalman iteration.
Plus I try to be gentle and save `errorMatrix` and `sampleEstimation` between steps =)

> Kalman filter wants `R` to be **1 - dimensional** based on my model. So I wonder where I'm wrong.
>
> Plus tell me if it's okay to propagate error and state matrices between Kalman Filters

I want `R` to be dependent on both **position** and **velocity**

My code:

```
public void iterate(float accelValue, Location location, long timestamp) {

    float dt = (timestamp - this.timestamp) / 1000f;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.location = location;

    // A = [ 1, dt ]
    //     [ 0,  1 ]
    A = getStateTransitionMatrix(dt);
    // B = [ dt^2/2 ]
    //     [ dt     ]
    B = getControlMatrix(dt);
    // Q = [ dt^4/4, dt^3/2 ]  * accelNoise
    //     [ dt^3/2, dt^2   ]
    Q = getProcessCovarianceMatrix(dt);
    // u = [ accelValue ]
    u = getControlVector(accelValue);
    // z = [ position, velocity ] From GPS on each step
    z = getMeasVector(location);
    // H = [ 1, 1 ]
    H = getMeasMatrix();
    // R = [ (posAccuracy * 2) ^ 2,                0 ]  from GPS on each step
    //     [ 0                    , (velAcc * 2) ^ 2 ]
    R = getMeasCovarianceMatrix(location);

    ProcessModel processModel = new DefaultProcessModel(
            A,
            B,
            Q,
            getStateEstimationVector(), // from previous kalmanFilter. Initial is x = [ 0, 0 ]
            getErrorCovarianceMatrix()); // from previous kalmanFilter. Initial is P = [ 1, 1 ] [ 1, 1 ]
    MeasurementModel measurementModel = new DefaultMeasurementModel(H, R);
    kalmanFilter = new KalmanFilter(processModel, measurementModel);
}
```

Predict and Correct

```
public void predictAndCorrect() {
    kalmanFilter.predict(u);
    kalmanFilter.correct(z);
}
```

In a nutshell consider something like:

```
Kalman kalman = new Kalman();

for(;;) { // consider this as callback when data is changed.
    kalman.iterate(accelValue, location, timestamp);
    kalman.predictAndCorrect();
    kalman.proceedResults();
}
```

Here is [docs example](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/filter.html). Maybe it will help somehow.

Thanks!